# A page resize issue

Tags: paper-size

The last years the default LARGE size for our books is set via geometry package as

```
\usepackage[a4paper,
        inner=2.25cm,
        outer=2.25cm,
        left=2.25cm,
        right=2.25cm,
        top=2.5cm,
        bottom=3cm,
        headsep=4mm]{geometry}
```

Unfortunately, the Ministry of Education made changes to the regulations regarding page sizes and the new page layout is specified via geometry as

```
\usepackage[a4paper,
        inner=1.55cm,
        outer=1.55cm,
        left=1.55cm,
        right=1.55cm,
        top=1.58cm,
        bottom=1.58cm,
        headsep=4mm]{geometry}
```

It is clear that if I recompile the book in LaTEX (I use MikTEX 2.9) with the new settings, the page layout will altered, and I have to perform the whole repagination of the book from scratch, a very time consuming process (there are 4 large books with about 900 pages each, that have to be processed in this way). Therefore, i would like to ask if it is possible to use the new settings, as they are defined by the second call of 'geometry' but without alter the current pagination and page layout. In other words I need to display the page as is, but with different margins (the new settings define smaller margins and I suppose that I ask for some type of page enlarging, in the hope that the quality of the contents does not get worse). Thanks a lot. Athanasios

Comment: Of course there is, use [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)!

Comment: With a new different aspect ratio of the new rules, simply enlarging the existing document will only be able to meet 3 out of the 4 margins.